# Spring + R2DBC: How to close DatabaseClient and TransactionalOperator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I can create DatabaseClient and TransactionalOperator in my Spring Boot app using:

```
@Autowired public App(ConnectionFactory factory) {
    DatabaseClient dc = DatabaseClient.create(factory);
    TransactionalOperator to = TransactionalOperator.create(new R2dbcTransactionManager(factory));
}
```

But how do I close the DatabaseClient and TransactionalOperator and free the connections/resources?

Is this the best way to create the database connection for R2DBC in a Spring Boot app?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: There's nothing to close unless you use a [connection pool](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-pool/).

Spring Data R2DBC's `DatabaseClient` allocates a connection per invoked operation. It's similar to `JdbcTemplate` that asks its `DataSource` to create a `Connection` for each method that you invoke. Once a method call is finished, it releases (closes) the connection.

Same applies for `DatabaseClient`. Once an operation finishes, the underlying connection is closed.

When using `TransactionalOperator` or `@Transactional` there's a slight change in the behavior but similar to JDBC: R2DBC Connections are bound during an active transaction to the transaction itself which makes `DatabaseClient` to reuse the same connection until the transaction completes. After a transaction is completed, the bound connection is released.

Comment: Why should you close connections from the pool? I think it's closed by `DatabaseClient`  as the regular connection.